# Installing odac as a part of deployment package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, deployment, odac

Need to install ODAC components along with a Forms application.
I am using VS2010 publish wizard to deploy the package to UNC path.
How could I deploy and install ODAC components (odp.net4) and Insta-client in a single deployment package ?